# Migrating from emotion to stitches: include two props in variants and breakpoints

Tags: css, reactjs, stitches

I am wondering how can I write this `styled-emotion` code in `stitches`. Basically I accept `onlyShowOnDesktop` and `breakpoint` props.

`breakpoint` is basically:

```
const breakpoint = isTopNavigationBreakPoint ? theme.defaultBreakpoints.xl : theme.defaultBreakpoints.m
```

Above returns either 1280 or 600 if isTopNavigationBreakPoint included or not.

The code looks like this:

```
export const Visible = styled.div<{
  onlyShowOnDesktop?: boolean
  breakpoint?: number
  selected?: boolean
}>`
  display: ${(props) => (props.onlyShowOnDesktop ? 'none' : 'unset')};
  ${({ onlyShowOnDesktop, breakpoint }) =>
    `
  @media(min-width: ${breakpoint}px) {
        display: ${onlyShowOnDesktop ? 'unset' : 'none'};
      }
  `}
`
```

I'm wondering how should we handle the `@media` part. So far I came up with this idea:

Have 2 variants with 2 breakpoints of 600 and 1280 and inside
include another variant for `onlyShowOnDesktop` with `true` and `false` objects with `display` property and `unset` and `none` value, but I am not sure if we should use variants nested in media queries?

Any suggestions would be much appreciated as I couldn't find any example online for stitches in this use-case.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone bumps into this in the future:

```
[isTopNavigationBreakPoint ? '@xlUp' : '@mUp']: {
  display: onlyShowOnDesktop ? 'unset' : 'none',
}
```

if we pass `isTopNavigationBreakPoint` as a prop, on `@xlUp` screen sizes set `display` to `'unset'`, if we also passed `onlyShowOnDesktop` prop else `display` to `'none'`  if we haven’t passed `onlyShowOnDesktop`.

Same for `@mUp` if we didn’t pass `isTopNavigationBreakpoint`